# Install Persistent Linux Mint on USB

Tags: linux-mint, partition, usb, system-installation, persistence

have a 32GB flash drive with live Linux Mint. I want to install a persistent version. I click the installation icon on the desktop and go through the prompts until I click "Something Else". I cannot get anything to work here. I know there are like 4 recommended partitions (root, home, boot, swap), which ones do I need and how large? Ive tried many combinations and the partitions fail to create each time. Thanks! Ive tried root as 6000MB primary, swap as 8000MB logical, and home as the rest.

Comment: Can you get it down to swap and root? If you don't know which partitions to create and how large, just having swap and root is a good starting point. Heck, with enough RAM you can even skip swap; but it's nice to have that safety net.

Comment: I just tried 16GB root primary and 16GB swap logical and it said that the swap partition failed. @EmmanuelRosa

Comment: To be frank, you'll need to be more specific than "the swap partition failed". It failed for a reason, and none of us can see your computer, so you need to provide clues. Screenshots/photos, the output of dmesg, ... something tangible.